# How to between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is,I have two string,alias two year value. I want to list the products between the two year! I use Mysql,DATA fieldt

```html
if($this->age[0]!="*" && $this->age[1]!="*") {
  $db->where("age",Array ($this->age[0],$this->age[1]),"BETWEEN");
} else {
  if($this->age[0]!="*")
  $db->where ("age",$this->age[0], ">=");
  if($this->age[1]!="*")
  $db->where ("age",$this->age[1], "<=");
}
```

This is my code. I think the problem with the string and the date. But how to solve it? :(

EDIT:
How to generate from string right value for MYSQL DATA field?

Comment: You mean you want to count the amount/difference of years between the two dates?

Comment: Kindly provide us the value of `$this->age[0]` and `$this->age[1]`

Comment: As @Noman said: can you provide us the values of the `$this->age` array?